# Prevent .appendChild from creating inside already filled div?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to create a tic tac toe game where you can play against `Math.floor(Math.random())` playing as `O`, with user is playing as `X`.  But when I click, it sometimes creates `O` in an already filled box.

I just want to allow one `P` tag per `div`.

**WARNING:** code extremely messy and over complicated(sorry).

html:

```
<body onload="createDivs()">
  <p id="demo"></p> 
</body>
```

css:

```
div {
  border: solid 2px black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var alternate = "O";
var count = 0;

function createDivs() {
  var t;
  var ai;
  var trackId = [];

  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    var d = document.createElement("DIV");
    document.body.appendChild(d);

    d.onclick = function() {
      if (count > 8) {
        return
      }

      var xP = document.createElement("P");
      var oP = document.createElement("P");

      var childCount = "childID" + count;

      xP.setAttribute("id", childCount);

      trackId.push(childCount);
      /*
      alert(trackId.toString());
      */

      count++;
      oP.setAttribute("id", "childID" + count);
      count++;

      if (alternate == 'O') {
        t = document.createTextNode("X");
        alternate = 'X';
        xP.appendChild(t);
        this.appendChild(xP);
        this.onclick = function() {};

        /*
        for (aa = 0; aa < 9; aa++) {
            var zed = "D"+aa;
            var bb = document.getElementById(zed).innerText;
            while (bb == 'X' || bb == 'O') {
                zed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
            } 
        }
        */

        if (count > 9) {} else {

          while (zed == 'X' || zed == 'O') {
            var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
            var zed = document.getElementById("D" + r).innerHTML;
            var zob = "D" + r;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = testConcat;
          }

          ai = document.createTextNode("O");
          alternate = 'O';
          oP.appendChild(ai);
          d.appendChild(oP);
        }
      }
    }

    var ii = document.createAttribute("id");
    ii.value = "D" + i;



    d.setAttributeNode(ii);
    var z = "D" + i;
    if (i == 3 || i == 6) {
      document.getElementById(z).style.clear = "left";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There were few issues in the code but the main problem was that when you are looking for the next empty slot, you are checking if the innerHTML of the Div is equal to "X" or "O". You can not use this logic since you are appending the **p** tag inside the div which has "X" or "O" as text.

So when you do **document.getElementById("D"+r).innerHTML** inside the while loop you will either get empty(this will work for you) or one of

```
<p>X</p>
<p>O</p>
```

(this will start causing problem) as this will make the code to append the child again on the same Div.

You should better check for the child elements inside a Div and if there is already a child element(slot is already filled) , code should look for another empty slot.

here is the updated code snippet

function createDivs() {
        var t;
        var ai;
        var trackId =[];
        var count = 0;
        var alternate  = "O";

```
    for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
        var d = document.createElement("DIV");
        document.body.appendChild(d);

        d.onclick = function() {
            if (count > 8) { 
                return
            }

            var xP = document.createElement("P");
            var oP = document.createElement("P");
            var zed = "X";
            var zod;

            var childCount = "childID"+count;

            xP.setAttribute("id", childCount);

            trackId.push(childCount);
            /*
            alert(trackId.toString());
            */

            count++;
            oP.setAttribute("id", "childID"+count);
            count++;

            if (alternate == 'O') {
                t = document.createTextNode("X");
                alternate = 'X';
                xP.appendChild(t);
                this.appendChild(xP);
                this.onclick = function() {};
                if (count > 9) {
                }
                else
                {
                while (zed == 'X' || zed == 'O') 
                {
                var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
                if(document.getElementById("D"+r).childElementCount == 0)
                zed = "";
                zob = "D"+r;
                }

                ai = document.createTextNode("O");
                alternate = 'O';
                oP.appendChild(ai);
                document.getElementById(zob).appendChild(oP);
            }
            }
        }

        var ii = document.createAttribute("id");
        ii.value = "D" + i;



        d.setAttributeNode(ii);
        var z = "D" + i;
        if (i == 3 || i == 6) {
                document.getElementById(z).style.clear = "left";
        }
    }
 }
```

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/FgQ5KbNEvBpnag9mn9qO?p=preview

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add jQuery you could do that with `if ($(this).find("p").length == 0)`

Here as a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/A__A/p0dax310/)